# I want to remove P and Br tags in Wordpress from auto generating but I want them to stay when I use them

Tags: html, wordpress

I have looked far and wide and I have found the answer of including `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );`

This works in the sense of stopping `<P>` and `<BR>` tags but it also removes them when I add them manually!

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want them to stay when I use them"? Long story short - when you add filter to remove these tags, you can also specify conditions on when and where to remove them.

Comment: Hey Richard!

So when I add the P or Br tags manually I want them to stay but I am trying to achieve it so that we stop WP automatically adding them? I hope this makes sense?

Is there a condition for this?

Many Thanks for you help and time :)